# vertical alignment in chemfig reaction scheme

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig

The vertical alignment for my reaction scheme is all over the place.

1. The horizontal bonds should be in one line
2. The OH-group's bond is further away from the C-atom then the O
3. There's a gap between the oxygen in the polyamide 12 polymer and the carbon atom
4. The names don't line up

[image]

**EDIT:**
As @cgnieder pointed out, using `\chemnameinit{}` solves issues 4.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{fixed length=true, atom sep=1.5em, arrow offset=6pt}


\begin{document}

\small
\chemnameinit{\chemfig{\vphantom{N}-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-{(}CH_2{)}_{11}-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]}}
\schemestart
\chemfig{\mathit{n}}
\chemname{\chemfig{NH_2-{(}CH_2{)}_{11}-C(=[1]O)-[7]OH}}{$\omega$-Amino-Laurylsäure}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
\chemname{\chemfig{\vphantom{N}-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-{(}CH_2{)}_{11}-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]}}{Polyamid 12}
\polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt]{li}{re}
\+
\chemfig{\mathit{n}}
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Wasser}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's `\chemnameinit` for that IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{fixed length=true, atom sep=1.5em, arrow offset=6pt}
\def\x{\vphantom{C}}
\begin{document}
\chemnameinit{\chemfig{\x-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]}}
\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{\x\mathit{n}\ NH_2|\x-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[1]O)-[7]OH}}{$\omega$-Amino-Laurylsäure}
    \arrow(.base east--.base west){0}[,0]\x\arrow(.east--.west)\x
    \arrow(.base east--.base west){0}[,0]
    \chemname{\chemfig{\x-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]}}{Polyamid 12}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=30pt]{li}{re}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{\mathit{n}\ H_2O}}{Wasser}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}
\end{document}
```